# OpenVPN not sending traffic to internet?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I've set up openvpn on my pi and am running into a small issue. I can connect to the VPN server and ping it just fine, and I can also connect to other machines on my local network. However I am unable, when connected to the VPN, to reach the outside world (either by name lookup or IP).

here are the details:

On the server the tun0 interface:

```
tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.8.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.8.0.2
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I can ping it just fine:

```
# ping -c 3 10.8.0.1
PING 10.8.0.1 (10.8.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.8.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.159 ms
64 bytes from 10.8.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.155 ms
64 bytes from 10.8.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.156 ms

--- 10.8.0.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
```

Routing table

```
# ip route show
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  metric 204 
10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.2 dev tun0 
10.8.0.2 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.1 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.6  metric 204
```

I also have ip traffic forwarding:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

I do not have any custom iptables rules (that I'm aware of).

On the client, I can connect to the VPN. Here is my tun0:

```
tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.8.0.6  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.8.0.5
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 21  bytes 1527 (1.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And on the client I can ping it:

```
sudo ping -c 3 10.8.0.6
PING 10.8.0.6 (10.8.0.6) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.8.0.6: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.035 ms
64 bytes from 10.8.0.6: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.026 ms
64 bytes from 10.8.0.6: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.032 ms

--- 10.8.0.6 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1998ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.026/0.031/0.035/0.003 ms
```

I can ssh from the client into another server on my LAN (192.168.1.x), however I cannot reach anything outside my LAN.

Here's some of the server logs at the bottom of this gist: https://gist.github.com/coleifer/6ef95c3008f130249933/edit

I am frankly out of ideas! I don't think it's my client because both my laptop and my phone (which has an openvpn client) exhibit the same behavior.

I had OpenVPN installed on this pi before using debian and it worked, so I don't think it's my router but of course anything is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by adding two iptables rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -a FORWARD -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
```